# How to Replace 'delta t' with 'a' in Mathematica Without Affecting Separate Instances of 'delta' or 't'?

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, algebraic-manipulation, semantic-matching

In Mathematica, how can I replace instances of `delta t` in an expression with `a`, while keeping instances of `delta` and `t` separate when they appear alone? For example, `delta^2 t` should be replaced with `a delta`, not `delta^2 t`. The following code doesn't work as expected; it results in `delta^2 t` instead of `a delta`.

```
replaceRule = delta t -> a;
expr = delta^2 t;
newExpr = expr /. replaceRule;
Print[newExpr];
```

The output is:

```
delta^2 t
```

instead of:

```
a delta
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I achieve the correct replacement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

replaceRule = delta^n1_. t^n2_. -> (n3 = Min[n1, n2];
    delta^(n1 - n3) t^(n2 - n3) a^n3);

expr = {delta^2 t, delta^3 t^5, delta^5 t^3};

newExpr = expr /. replaceRule

(* {a delta, a^3 t^2, a^3 delta^2} *)
```